# Hierarchical filtering in a relational database

Tags: database, database-design, hierarchical-data

I have a bunch of items in my program that all belong to a specific category.  I'd like to return only the items that belong to that category.  The problem is that categories can have parent categories.  For example, let's say there's a category "Stuff" with the child category "Food" with the child category "Fruit".  I have the items, Apple, Pear, Chocolate, and Computer.

If I want to display all of the fruits, it's easy to do a database query with a "WHERE item.category = FRUIT_ID" clause.  However, if I want all foods to be included, I need a way to get the fruits in there, too.

I know that some databases, like Oracle, have a notion of recursive queries, and that might be the right solution, but I don't have a lot of experiences with hierarchical data and am looking for general suggestions.  Assume I have unlimited control over the database schema, the category tree only goes maybe 5 categories deep maximum, and I need it to be as ridiculously fast as possible.

Comment: Ridiculous fast for querying, or ridiculous fast for updating? Must pick a maximum of 1 (one) choice.

Comment: Let's go with querying, then.  Updating will be significantly rarer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [adjacency list model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) - it's not perfect (it's very slow to update), but in some situations (hierarchical queries), it's a great representation, especially for problems like yours.

Comment: That's a fascinating model that I did not know about before.  Seems very advantageous.  I wonder if I could do something sneaky to not have to renumber as often.  Maybe leave large gaps between the numbers so that I could toss a few extra categories in occasionally without renumbering.  Either way, a lot to think about, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's [a whole book](http://books.google.com/books?id=uw2lq2o4VbUC&dq=sql+hierarchies+for+smarties&printsec=frontcover&source=bl&ots=DrMY7ompMH&sig=cfxlz-J5lNsr9NdNjM-e3wr1Lt8&hl=en&ei=d55LS5HoAc-2lAer5ZWKDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CA8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=&f=false) full of design strategies for representing trees in SQL. It's worth looking at just for the sheer clever points.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your category tree is small enough to be cached, you might be better off keeping the category tree in memory and have a function over that tree that will generate a list of category id's that are below a given category.

Then when you query the database, you just use an `IN` clause with the list of child IDs

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  It intuitively feels like a bit more of a hack than the adjacency list approach, but I'll keep it in mind.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to separate the hierarchy from the actual categorization. For instance, an apple could be categorized as both a fruit and a food. The categorization has no knowledge that a fruit is a food, but you could define that somewhere else. Then, your query would be as simple as `where category='food'`.

Alternatively, you could go through the hierarchy before building your query and it would require something like `where category='food' or category='fruit'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your database schema is quite fine, but the implementation of this search really depends on your specific RDBMS.  A lot of them have ways to perform this sort of recursion.  One example I can think of is SQL Server's support of [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) which are lightning fast alternatives to those nasty cursors.

If you specify which RDBMS you're using, you might get more specific answers.